# How can I bind a repeat to a table using an object literal?

Tags: angularjs, binding, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this object called ct.items.columns ... and inside I have two strings , "id" and "name" .

And I want to bind in angular to build an dynamic table with two columns.. "id" and "name" from my literal.

I tried this:

```
<table border ="1">
     <tr class="active">
       <th ng-repeat = "a in ct.items.columns">
    </tr>
</table>
```

And I get nothing. My controller is set up properly.. I can make other bindings. In the object ct.items I have two properties.. columns and query... and in columns 0 - id and 1-name .

Comment: Paste your object here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your object but you can make dynamic table like this.

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="(heading,val) in ct.items.columns">{{heading}}</th>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="(heading,val) in ct.items.columns">{{val}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wA8LC/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is very nice. thanks. now I need to put some values from table inside my fields... and make the rest of the tr.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <table border ="1">
      <th>
        <td>id</id>
        <td>name</td>
    </th>
       <tr class="active" ng-repeat ="item in ct.items.columns">
           <th >{{item.id}}</th>
           <th >{{item.name</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: this is good and I thought at this.. but I need to auto-generate my fields..with th repeat and I didn't knew how to display the value. thank you for your help.